# Defining a method in a for Loop JAVA

Tags: java, swing, loops, methods, for-loop

So, I'm trying to define a set of methods for a large set of buttons, and I figured I could do it in a for loop, but I'm getting a syntax error which I can't decipher... Here's a simplified version of the code I want to use... The error is: "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)"

```
JMenu blocks = new JMenu("Block");
menuBar.add(blocks);

for (int i=0; i < 9; i++){
  public void action() {
      System.out.println(i+"");
  }
  JMenuItem blockName = new JMenuItem(i+"");
  blockName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
          action();
      }
  });
  blocks.add(blockName);
}
```

Comment: @PaulTomblin not necessary, both work

Comment: What line gives you that error?

Comment: @PaulTomblin actually using String concatenation to convert an `int` to a `String` is not a good practice (since behind the scenes you are creating an unnecessary `StringBuilder`). It is rather recommended to use `String.valueOf`. And anyway, `""+i` will output the same result as `i+""`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java methods are not first-class objects (or second or third-class objects; in fact, methods are not objects at all). You need to move the method into one of the classes - either your top class, or the anonymous inner class that you defined, like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < 9; i++) {
    // You cannot access i from methods of the anonymous inner class
    // because it is not final, but you can make a final copy
    final int iCopy = i;
    JMenuItem blockName = new JMenuItem(i+"");
    blockName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        // It is OK to define additional methods here:
        public void action() {
            System.out.println(iCopy+"");
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            action();
        }
    });
    blocks.add(blockName);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Delete your `action` method and place your code inside the ActionListener

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
      System.out.println(i+"");
      // ... etc.
  }
```

---

As others have mentioned in their answers, `i` will not be accessible from within `actionPerformed`. Specifically, see @dasblinkenlight's answer for a more thorough response.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining a new method inside another method:

```
  public void action() {
      System.out.println(i+"");
  }
```

You need to extract this outside of the current method.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have a method declartion insede for loop. The loop must be in a method body.

```
 private void init(JMenu blocks) {
   for (int i=0; i < 9; i++){

    JMenuItem blockName = new JMenuItem(i+"");
    blockName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
              handleAction(arg0);
          }
      });
    blocks.add(blockName);
  }
}


   public void handleAction(ActionEvent event) {

       Object source = event.getSource(); 

       if(source instanceof JMenuItem) {
           JMenuItem item = (JMenuItem) source;
           System.out.println(item.getName());
       ) 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

That is simply not valid `Java`. Consider creating an `Action` instance in your for loop and use that action to back the `JMenuItem`, e.g.

```
JMenu blocks = new JMenu("Block");
menuBar.add(blocks);

for (int i=0; i < 9; i++){
    Action action = new AbstractAction(){
      public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
        System.out.println( "Whatever but not i as that cannot be accessed" );
        System.out.println( "or you need to introduce a final variable" );
      }
    };  
    JMenuItem blockName = new JMenuItem(i+"");
    blockName.setAction( action );  
    blocks.add(blockName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        JMenuItem blockName = new JMenuItem(i + "");
        blockName.setAction(new MyAction(i));
        blocks.add(blockName);
    }
}

class MyAction extends AbstractAction {
    int param;

    public MyAction(int myParameter) {
        param = myParameter;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(param));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can'd define nested methods, just nested classes [*inner classes*], or a class nested in a method [*local classes*].

If you want your `ActionListener` to be aware of the `i`, you can't directly, or you will stumble upon such error:

> local variable i is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

so you should extend your `JMenuItem`, or better design your application in order to decouple UI from current model status.